# need to edit php file of child theme to remove an element

Tags: php, themes

Im a novice - I need to know about how do i access and then delete a line on line 129 of my theme. like shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I need a stepwise guide through my wp-admin dashboard. I dont access FTP and i am using a page builder to make my website.

Comment: All the files are under Appearance->Editor. Look for your file and edit it

Answer (score 0):

Editing your theme files is not a good idea. If you don't fully understand the theme, you might break it. Moreover, if the theme is updated, it will overwrite all your edits.

The correct way to do this is make a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). You don't need ftp access. You can also upload it from `dashboard->themes->add-bew-theme->upload`.

Here are tree steps to follow:

1. Download `style.css` from the original theme. Remove everything but the header. In that header change Theme Name and Description. Don't touch the Template line.
2. Download the template file that you want to change. Remove the line you want to get rid of.
3. Create a `functions.php` file to include an action `wp_enqueue_scripts` as described in the link.

Upload the three files. Use live preview tot test if everything is going according to plan.